# Erro ao tentar criar a primeira dependencia com o comando composer init

Tags: php, composer, prompt

Boa noite, estou estudando php, estou na parte de aprender a usar o composer, ao criar a primeira dependencia do composer quando ele chega em uma parte ele da o seguinte erro ...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ja procurei a soluçao em varios lugares mas nada resolvel, oque pode ser sera ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta redefinir o repositório do composer e usar apenas protocolo https...

```
composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org
composer config -g github-protocols https ssh
```

Isto vai resolver automaticamente o ficheiro `composer.json` se o mesmo conter erros.

Comment: Deu certo, deixa eu voltar para os estudos agora, brigadao.